# How to know if an input is only partially complete in Roslyn's ScripEngine

Tags: c#, read-eval-print-loop, roslyn

I'm building a REPL with Roslyn.

How can I figure out if the input to the session is only partially complete:

```
> 1+1;
> 2 //that works
> int MyMethod(string a){
  //error here, i'd like to continue writing the expression
```

This code shows the problem:

```
var engine = new ScriptEngine();
var session = engine.CreateSession();
var input = "int MyMethod(string a){";
session.Execute(input); //Exception: error CS1513: } expected
```

What do I have to do to find out if the `input` is complete or not? So I can show another line in my REPL until the expression is complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The interactive window that is part of the CTP uses the `Syntax.IsCompleteSubmission` API for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SyntaxTree.ParseText` and `GetDiagnostics()` to check if syntax is correct. If not, you will probably want to append this line to some buffer and check this buffer until it will be valid.

```
var st = SyntaxTree.ParseText(input);
var errors = st.GetDiagnostics();
```

**Note**: there always be some error (even for simple `1+1` expression) so you will have to filter it out by default:

[image]